# How minimze pdf filesize using post processing while keeping formfields and images?

Tags: linux, pdf, ghostscript, filesize

I need to minimize a pdf file which will later be filled programmatically. Some of the "text" in it is really an image. Sadly I don't have the original file to fix that. So I can't just remove the background image.

My current attempt is:

```
gs -dShowAcroForm=false -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray -sOutputFile=OUTPUT_NAME INPUT_NAME
```

I included `-dShowAcroForm=false` because it was mentioned that this would keep the form fields. Sadly this didn't help and form fields are removed by this command.

The answer can use a different command and doesn't have to use ghostscript. Solutions where I can try out different dpi's would be better.

**EDIT1**

The two files in question are:

https://github.com/Aeolitus/Sephrasto/blob/master/src/Sephrasto/Data/Charakterb%C3%B6gen/Langer%20Charakterbogen.pdf

https://github.com/Aeolitus/Sephrasto/blob/master/src/Sephrasto/Data/Charakterb%C3%B6gen/Standard%20Charakterbogen.pdf

As shown in the ghostscript command above, minimal loss of dpi and color transformation to black & white would be acceptable for me in order to receive a smaller file size.

I tried using `cpdf -squeeze`. Form fields are kept correctly. On `Langer Charakterbogen.pdf` it saved 13% (0,5mb) and on `Standard Charakterbogen.pdf` it saved 6% (0,2mb). I would like to reduce it even more, so I accept lossy compression, too.

Comment: There's no guarantee that any PDF file is not already at the minimum size for the target quality, so there is no guarantee that anything you do will reduce the size of the final PDF file. You can look at the documentation to find out how to sacrifice quality for size (downsampling images, converting to gray, etc) but without seeing the input file I can't offer any specific guidance. It's entirely possible the file is already 'minimised'. The on thing Ghostscript's pdfwrite doesn't currently do is write compressed xref and object streams though that usually saves very little space.

Comment: Great idea and thank you very much! I updated my question, included a link to both pdf files in question and tried `cpdf` with `-squeeze. I will look at the other cl arguments it has and try them out.

Comment: Thank you. Ghostscript didn't work for me because it removes the form fields. What is a pdfvieweditor? The resolution is too low. The text in the image is very hard to read. I would go for less compression and black/white probably. What tool are you using?